# Is it possible to link two buttons to two different ibactions in the same ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, hyperlink, uibutton, ibaction

i work on a project and i have two buttons, one for sending a mail and the second one is an imagepicker.

I've able to link my first button to my `@IBAction sendMail` but I can't do the same with my `@IBAction imagePicker`.

When i do a "drag and drop" from the storyboard to the interface file my ViewController nothing happens. The blue strip is here but no window pop up to create the link..

A bit of help would appreciate. 
Here is the code :

```
internal class ViewController : UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    override internal func viewDidLoad()

    @IBAction internal func 
         sendEmail(_ sender: any)

    @IBAction internal func 
         imagePicker(_ sender: UIButton)
```

}

Comment: please, share the code of your viewController so we can help you.

Comment: @ReyBruno Hey, here is the update !
Thank you for your time

Comment: Try first write your func @IBAction internal func imagePicker(_ sender: UIButton) and then drag to that function to the button in the storyboard.
Sometimes, connect outlets to code in xCode is not working, but connect the func to the outlet work.

Comment: @ReyBruno I created the func IBAction func imagePicker(_ UIButton)  (code updated in the post)
I tried to link the func to the button but it "didn't worked", nothing happened . There a special way to do this ? (I tried the drag and drop AND also the CTRL + drag and drop)
Thank you for your time

Comment: Wait, your code is literally that? Or you just shortened it?
If your code is literally that, you need use {} in the beginning and the end of your functions.

Comment: @ReyBruno No, it is the code from the interface of ViewController in my "real" there is { }, no worries ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have already solved it, but the problem may originate because you are viewing the file interface instead of the file.

On your storyboard, touch the yellow circle of your ViewController.

[image]

Then touch the button with the 2 rings in the top right corner of the xCode:

[image]

Now change from automatic to manual:

[image]

Finally, find your ViewController without (interface) in the name and connect de action there.

[image]

If you did it all rigth, now you can see a white circle in the left of your action like this:

[image]